# ¿Cómo Des-Seleccionar un select Múltiple?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>select multiple</title>

    <link href="styles/multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="multiselect.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<select id='testSelect1' multiple>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Item 5</option>
</select>
<script>
    document.multiselect('#testSelect1');
</script>
<button onclick="anadir();">añadir</button>
</body>
```

Entonces lo conecto a este .js el cual hace que se marquen todas las opciones:

```
//multiselect collection
window.multiselects = [];

if (typeof ($) != 'undefined') {
    //jQuery extension for multiselect
    $.fn.multiselect = function () {
        //if no elements passed - it is not an error
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }

        if (this.length != 0) {
            $(this).each(function (i, e) {
                var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
                if (index == -1) {
                    var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                    window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                    window.multiselects._items.push(e);

                    res.push(inputItem)
                } else {
                    res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
                }
            });
        }

        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : $(res);
    };

    $(document).click(function (event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    });
} else {
    document.multiselect = function(selector) {
        var res = [];
        if (!window.multiselects._items) {
            window.multiselects._items = [];
        }

        m_helper.each(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(e) {
            var index = window.multiselects._items.indexOf(e);
            if (index == -1) {
                var inputItem = new Multiselect(e);
                window.multiselects.push(inputItem);
                window.multiselects._items.push(e);

                res.push(inputItem)
            } else {
                res.push(window.multiselects[index]);
            }
        });

        return res.length == 1 ? res[0] : res;
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        hideMultiselects(event);
    };
}

function hideMultiselects(event) {
    m_helper.each(window.multiselects, function(e) {
        if (document.getElementById(e._getItemListIdentifier()).offsetParent &&
                !m_helper.parent(event.target, e._getIdentifier())) {
            e._hideList(e, event);
        }
    });
}
```

Mi pregunta sería: ¿qué línea de código modifico para que no se me muestren todas las opciones marcadas?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo el ejemplo tuyo haria algo asi

```
<select id='testSelect1' multiple>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
    <option value='5'>Item 5</option>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick="miFuncion();">DesSeleccionar</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function miFuncion(){
    var elements = document.getElementById("testSelect1").options;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }//end for
  }//end function
```

de esta manera sencilla deseleccionamos los multiselect !!
otra forma seria usando jquery algo asi:

```
$("#testSelect1 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

[Aqui el ejemplo realizado](http://jsfiddle.net/vgd0bf3f/2/)

Comment: en el codigo que has añadido creas un boton para des-seleccionar; pero lo que busco es que al momento de cargar la pagina, me muestre las opciones desmarcadas

Comment: busca una solucion practica manda a llamar a la funcion deseleccionar

Comment: window.onload = miFuncion;

Comment: con eso llamas a la funcion de javascript que deselecciona tu multiselect, al cargar la pagina

Comment: sigue manteniendose marcado

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes realizar cargando el valor de las opciones

```
   <select multiple value={[1,3]}>
       <option value="1">opcion 1</option>
       <option value="2">opcion 2</option>//Esta estará por consecuencia no seleccionada
       <option value="3">opcion 3</option>
       <option value="4">opcion 4</option>//Esta estará por consecuencia no seleccionada
    </select>
```